# Narrator is reading href value in the HTML pages

Tags: uiaccessibility

I am trying to give the narrator support for the UWP application with the webview. when the narrator is reading the webview content (local html pages), it reads the value inside the anchor tag.
My HTML code looks like `<a href="https://www.google.com">search></a>` when the narrator is reading it reads as Search link value equals https://www.google.com
is there any way to stop narrator reading the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still an issue for you but if you don't want the screen reader to announce the actual URL, you could always use an aria-label to provide an alternate. Keep in mind though. Some screen readers may still read both the aria-label and the URL, but for the most part, you shouldn't have any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to suppress the `href` on anchors using the `role="button"` attribute.

Comment: You should not do this if it's an actual link. Role button is to tell the assistive technology that the expected behavior is not the native default behavior of an anchor element.

Comment: > The button role should be used for clickable elements that trigger a response when activated by the user.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/button_role

Comment: Also note that this question is specific to the Xbox Narrator on UWP webview.